# Group and subgroups problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$ a subgroup. Furthermore, let $\lvert G \setminus H \rvert < \infty$ (i.e. the set-theoretical complement of $H$ in $G$ is finite).
>   Show that either $\rvert G\lvert < \infty$ or $H = G$.

Now the second case is clear:
If $\lvert G\setminus H\rvert = 0$, then  obviously $H = G$.
So let $\lvert G\setminus H\rvert =: n$ and $g\in G\setminus H$.

From here I am not sure how to proceed, since I know nothing about $G\setminus H$ since it is not necessarily a subgroup.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $|H|=|G|$? Certainly $H=G$ is not required.

Comment: The $H = G$ in the problem or the one in my "proof"? The exercise is correct as stated. For my proof: If $H \subseteq G$ and $\lvert G\backslash H\rvert = 0$, isn't then $H = G$?

Comment: No, it's not correct. For example, $G=\mathbb Z$, $H=2\mathbb Z$ is a counterexample. But it may be what is written.

Comment: Well but $\mathbb Z \backslash 2\mathbb Z$ is not finite.

Comment: @MattSamuel It's not a counterexample, because $G\setminus H$ is infinite (it's not the set of cosets).

Comment: Yes, I am not talking about the quotient group but the difference of sets.

Comment: I've edited to make that more clear. @lappen68 you can use \setminus for the set difference in MathJax, it has different spacing than \backslash, so it's slightly less confusing (I hope).

Comment: Yes, I will do that in the future. Thank you :)

Comment: @Arnaud I see. Sometimes $G\H$ is used to denote the set of left cosets, while $G/H$ is the set of right cosets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $g\in G\setminus H$, and define a map
$$\varphi : G\to G:x\mapsto gx.$$Then $\varphi$ is bijective. Furthermore, if $gx\in H$, then $x\notin H$, since otherwise $g\in Hx^{-1}=H$. Thus $\varphi^{-1}(H)\subset G\setminus H$, hence it is finite. Thus $H$ is finite, and thus $G=(G\setminus H) \cup H$ is finite as well.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $H \subsetneq G$. Choose a set of left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$. Except for the representative of $H$ (can be the identity or any element of $H$) this set must lie in the finite set $G \backslash H$. It follows $|G:H|$ is finite. But there exists a $t \notin H$, and then $tH \cap H = \emptyset$, whence $tH \subseteq G\backslash H$. Note that $|tH|=|H|$, so it follows that $H$ is finite. Hence $|G|=|G:H| \cdot |H|$ is finite.